# Include original picture's file on a iPhoto slideshow

Tags: photos.app, idvd, slideshow

There is a simple way to include the original picture's file of a `iPhoto` slideshow?
I create a slideshow with `iPhoto`, select `Share` and `iDvd`. Now I have the slideshow on `iDvd` and I can burn or export in `VIDEO_TS` or `.IMG.` What is the **best** way to have the burned dvd video with the original picture's file inside too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iDVD, in the Advanced Menu, there is an option to Edit DVD-ROM contents.  There you can simply add whatever content you want, including dragging in the photos from iPhoto.

Comment: Ok, tryed and works like a charm!

Comment: glad it worked out out :)